# Reordering list is not working with collection-repeat in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am facing the same issue. Reordering is working with ng-repeat but when I am doing the same thing using collection repeat than it's not working.

Here is the link which is working with the `ng-repeat`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nbCmH

and the same thing with collection repeat which is not working

```
http://codepen.io/saurabhgarg/pen/cbqgn
```

Can you please tell me how it will possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this implmentation may nt be possible as it says in the ionic forum http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/reordering-in-collection-repeat/6179